# Selenium in Mac OS and Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, selenium

How Running Selenium Java on Eclipse is different for both the systems Mac OS and Windows ?
Is there  a lot difference between them ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference but setup and configuration is little diffrent

Comment: No difference in terms of coding in any of these , Right ?